# Как сделать красивый url в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Сейчас url вида /cat.php?id=catname. Как сделать, чтобы url был вида /cat/catname? С .htaccess знаком плохо, поэтому все, что получилось, так это RewriteRule ^cat/$ cat.php [L]

Comment: Фреймворки используйте, там как раз реализуют красивые адреса страниц. `cat/.../.../` и т.д. Например, CI.

Comment: [Хорошая статья про способности этого файла][1].


  [1]: http://workhack.ru/blog/trash/186.html

Answer (score 3):

[Наглядное руководство по htaccess и mod_rewrite для новичков](http://www.seoschool.ru/search-engine-optimization-seo/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide.html).

Comment: Сделал так "RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]", вроде все работает, НО почему то не работают шаблоны. То есть показывает голый текст... Почему так?

Comment: Потому что пути надо указывать абсолютные

Пример:

    url: /product/15/
    style: style/style.css
    -->style: /product/15/style/style.css

Но там же его нет, правильно? Поэтому указываем путь от корня сайта:

    style: /style/style.css

Обратите внимание на слэш в начале.

Answer (score 3):

ИМХО лучший вариант использования mod_rewrite это непосредственный парсинг REQUEST_URI в самом ядре сайта, например:

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Если не файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Если не директория
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Запускаем index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
function ParseURL_ModRewrite()
{
    //Чиста URI
    $uri=preg_replace('#[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$#i', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $get_reqs=explode('/', $uri, 20);

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($get_reqs);$i++)
    {
        if($get_reqs[$i]=='' && ($i+1)==sizeof($get_reqs))
            break;

        $_GET['value'.($i-1)]=$get_reqs[$i];    
    }
}
ParseURL_ModRewrite();

//Вывод на экран всех параметров GET
print_r($_GET);
?>
```