# Mod_rewirte и регулярные выражения помогите составить

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php, регулярные-выражения

Есть url вида `site.com/index.php?c=journal&id=2` , его нужно сделать доступным по адресу `site.com/journal2`

Можете помочь составить регулярное выражение, чтобы это сделать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?c=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: в вопросе хотят не через слэш, а слитно: `/journal2`

Comment: а потом парсить строку? И к этому всему еще и ЧПУ отдыхает.

Comment: ТС не следует стандартам, привычным вам. Зачем навязывать?

Comment: Это как вариант, я не навязываю, в конце-концов и другие ответы есть. А вот на счет следования стандартам, а точнее не следования, то я надеюсь все осознают к чему это может привести.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]+[0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$ /index.php?c=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего обрабатывать URI непосредственно в PHP файле, для примера в htaccess вбивается следующее :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Если не файл
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
# Если не директория
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Запускаем index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Здесь правило RewriteRule (.*) index.php отправляет выполнение для любых запросов в наш index.php. А обработать уже URI можно пропарсив $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Вот тут я кому то это уже советовал [link text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75387/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-url-%D0%B2-htaccess?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=75583#75583)

Comment: Т.е. получается пользователь заходит на site.com/journal2 его кидает на index.php, где уже обрабатывается запрос, но ведь на index.php сервер кинет его на site.com/index.php?c=journal&id=2 ?